# Change bullet colour in VBA and make text bold/italic

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I wrote some VBA code to automate powerpoint slides per row of my excel file. So I run my code from excel and get a powerpoint from it.

Everything works great so far, only thing is that I would like to change the colour of the bullett point that is created with the Placeholder(2) line. Also how can I make it so that some of the DataRow.Cells are printed bold/italics?

I have tried looking online but the code seems so different, I have no idea how to make us of it.

Code:

```
Option Explicit

'reference to PPTX via een sub routine
Sub Powerpointmkn()

    Dim DataRange As Range
    Dim DataRow As Range
    Dim ppt As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim Presentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim Slide As PowerPoint.Slide
    
   
    Set ppt = New PowerPoint.Application
    Set Presentation = ppt.Presentations.Add
    
    ppt.Visible = True
    

    Set DataRange = Range("A1:H23")
    
    For Each DataRow In DataRange.Rows
       Set Slide = Presentation.Slides.AddSlide(Presentation.Slides.Count + 1, Presentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(2))
       Slide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = DataRow.Cells(1, 8) & " " & DataRow.Cells(1, 1) & " " & DataRow.Cells(1, 2)
       Slide.Shapes.Placeholders(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = DataRow.Cells(1, 7) & " " & DataRow.Cells(1, 5) & " " & DataRow.Cells(1, 3) & " " & DataRow.Cells(1, 4)
    Next DataRow
End Sub
```

I have tried to make another Sub which would then try to go over my powerpoint and correct every bullet point... but so far its been a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of setting the bullet color. Can use the properties chain in your code.

```
activepresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Placeholders(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Font.Color=vbmagenta
```